# function to return least significant digits of a number

Tags: algorithm, methods

I am trying to write a simple method (any language)  which gives 6 least significant digits.

```
method giveSD(n) {
   return 6 least significant number;
}
```

for example if n is 1963222, then the method should return 963222.

Comment: What have you tried? Look at the various arithmetic operators available, and see whether any of those might help you...

Comment: _I am trying to write java function_ so i removed `C` tag.

Comment: What do you want to obtain for negative numbers ? (Do you even care ?)

Comment: What is your requirement? Is it return 8 LSD or 6 LSD?

Comment: Do you mean like `return abs(n) % 1000000`?

Answer (score 13):

Use Math! As simple as `return n % 1000000;`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes, from ones place. This is what required.

Comment: I was just trying to "implement" the example.

Comment: The example is opposite of what he wrote..

Comment: @MarounMaroun: reread the question. This answer is just perfect.

Comment: Yes.. My mistake :) +1 ! Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Hope Will Be Useful.

```
int giveSD(int i) {
    String sValue=String.valueOf(i);
    return Integer.parseInt(sValue.substring(sValue.length()-8, sValue.length()));
}
```

Comment: `String.valueOf(i)` should be assigned to a variable instead of compute it 3x. The use of String is excessively costly when you want to perform mathematic op. It's the opposite of optimization(Furthermore, this returns an Integer instead of an int)

Comment: @ndj Yes.. It should be stored! Edited.